# Unit testing a component that uses other components (wrapping)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have not been able to find answers to my question and I'm not sure if its because nobody else struggled with it before? Or my wording is incorrect. So here I am.

Let's say we have a Dialog component that looks like this (some parts were left off for simplicity sake):

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

export default class Dialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, dialogCss, ...modalProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal role="dialog" {...modalProps}>
        <div>
          <div dialogCss={dialogCss}>{children}</div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code, `Dialog` component uses `Modal` component under the hood.

How should I approach unit testing?

- Do I unit test Dialog specific functionalities only (which is only css)?
- Do I unit test Dialog specific functionality AND Modal functionality through Dialog?

For example, Modal has a boolean prop called `open` that renders or doesn't render the component. I already tested Modal, and in that Modal test, I test that `open` prop set to false or true is respected.

Dialog also uses `open`, do I need to test that "Dialog" also respects the `open` prop set to false or true?

This is how it is currently being tested and it is testing Dialog specific functionality ONLY because my reasoning is: even though Dialog is using Modal under the hood, since Modal itself has been tested, it will be redundant to test it through Dialog again. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from './Dialog';

const testCss = {
  'background-color': '#fff',
  color: '#000',
};

test('respects dialogCss prop', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <Dialog open={true} dialogCss={() => testCss}>
      <div>hello</div>
    </Dialog>
  );

  expect(getByTestId('dialogbox')).toHaveStyle({ ...testCss });
});

test('renders children', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <Dialog open={true}>
      <div data-testid="test">hello</div>
    </Dialog>
  );

  expect(getByTestId('test')).not.toBeNull();
});
```

And here is the dispute: someone said `your dialog is still a dialog and you'd expect anything that depends on it to not break`, meaning we SHOULD be testing that Modal is working through Dialog. Meaning that Dialog should test that `open` is being respected, even though Modal itself is testing for it.

Two opposing thoughts, and we are all new to front end unit testing. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for your time and help!